# Additional hot cache by disabling ingestion time policy

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have enabled ingestion time policy on my table and then I am keeping latest 1 day of data for the table in hot cache. I am trying to assess how much extra cache I can get for actual data if I turn off the ingestion time policy. So basically I can imagine that since the ingestion time policy is enabled, for every row I have an extra column value ingestion_time which is of datetime type. So if this occupies N bytes to store a single datetime value , then if I have X rows in hot cache , I am wasting my cache by X*N bytes -- which could otherwise be used by some additional actual data (considering ingestion utilization is over 100% already) So I am trying to assess how much cache I am wasting by enabling ingestion time policy.

Answer (score 2):

**a.** I wouldn't necessarily call it a "waste"

- Unless you're not using the `ingestion_time()` in any of your queries. in which case - you can decide you want to disable the policy, which is enabled by default. (Though you may change your mind later, when you actually need it, and regret that decision)

**b.** In order to get an estimation of the sizes (i.e. disk cache utilization), you can run `.show table TABLENAME` to see stats (including original/compressed/index sizes) for each column.

- *Beware:* this isn't a lightweight command, so don't run it too frequently.
- Look at a `datetime`-typed column whose values are close in time to when the data gets ingested as reference - so that it resembles the content of `ingestion_time()`. You can compare that to other columns in the table.
- The actual size on disk is `ExtentSize`.

**c.** Remember that Kusto/ADX is (mostly, excluding RowStore used in streaming ingestion) a column store technology - data is stored in columns, not in rows (as your original question implies). You can read more about the technology in t[his whitepaper](https://azure.microsoft.com/mediahandler/files/resourcefiles/azure-data-explorer/Azure_Data_Explorer_white_paper.pdf).